# .NET Core MongoDB driver connection fail after database failover

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a .NET 6 application (running in cloud foundry) which connects to MongoDB (hosted on different server). Application is using MongoDB.Driver version 2.11.6.

Application starts failing whenever MongoDB failover happens. If we restart the app in cloud foundry it resolves the issue.

I searched online and added "connect=replicaSet&" in mongodb connection string but that didn't resolve the problem.

Connection string format:

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@<server1>:<port>,<server2>:<port>,<server3>:<port>/<database_Name>?connect=replicaSet&ssl=true&replicaSet=mongo<port>
```

[image]

Comment: you should provide full connecion string and error message

Comment: Added connection string format and full error in the question.

Comment: it's not full error. The error contains description of the server in this node: ` Servers: [`

Comment: @dododo I just removed server names from the error message and added <server> <port> as place holder. Can't share actual server names here.

Comment: I mean that error message contains a json with description of the server state. Your message is ended on `HeartbeatException` field in particular in stack trace `ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at`. It's just a long string that contains exception message, but the there are more fields after this, ie you should provide the untruncated json description

Comment: you may see it here https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/frequently_encountered_issues/. In the first example, the description of the server consist of 1 server, in your case it will be, I guess, 3

Comment: Try to add `readPreference=primaryPreferred` to connection string

Comment: How many mongod servers do you have in the replica set?  The error message shows 2, but is it also showing "connection refused" for one of them.  1 out of 2 is not a majority, so in a 2-node replica set you cannot elect a primary unless both nodes are up.  Since the operation is requesting readPreference primary, it is expected to fail if there is no primary node.

Comment: @dododo attached full error

Comment: @Joe total 3 servers are in replica set. Attached full error

Comment: you have no primary (2 secondaries and one failed node). So failover for some reason didn't happen. You should analyze what happens in the server logs (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/) at the time when error happens. Additionally, you may want to look at what the server status in the shell, run the following command: `db.runCommand({ hello : 1  })`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, `primaryPreffered` option may help with read operations, but it's just workaround without a clue what is the actual error

Comment: @Anil, also it makes sense to check this behavior on latest driver.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Where did you get the `connect=replicaSet` option? I never heard about it, and it is [not documented](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/) either

Comment: `connect=replicaSet` - it's a legacy option that has no power in this case

Comment: This is looking more like a DBA question than a programming one.

Comment: @dododo I was looking for solution of this problem and found few suggestions to use connect=replicaSet. However it didn't help.

Comment: @Anil `connect` is a legacy option that (in this case) forces driver to be in replica set mode (multi server), however replicaSet option you specified does the same